# How to map collections using Automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, automapper

I have following  classes

```
 public class StateDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string StateName { get; set; }
        public string StateCode { get; set; }

    }
 public class CountryDto
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        public List<StateDto> States { get; set; }
    }



public class Country : Entity, IValidatableObject
    {
        public Country()
        {
            States=new List<State>();
        }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
 // Few code related to IvalidatableObject removed
        public virtual ICollection<State> States { get; private set; }

        public void AddNewStatesInCountry(State state)
        {

            state.CountryId = Id;
            States.Add(state);

        }

       public bool IsDuplicateStateCodeExisits(string stateCode)
        {
            return States.Any(s => s.StateCode == stateCode);
        }

    }

public class State : Entity, IValidatableObject
    {
        public string StateName { get; set; }
        public string StateCode { get; set; }
        public int CountryId { get; set; }

      // Few code related to IvalidatableObject removed
    }
```

and i am mapping this two classes using following code

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<State, StateDto>();
    Mapper.CreateMap<Country, CountryDto>();  // Mapping Country to CountryDto
```

But i am getting this error while executing my code

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException : Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
Country -> CountryDto
Domain.ErpBase.CountryAgg.Country -> Application.ErpBase.Dto.CountryDto

Destination path:
CountryDto

Source value:
Domain.ErpBase.CountryAgg.Country
```

Whats wrong with my mapping, How can  solve this problem. is there any special setup required for mapping collection in the classes

NB: i tried countryMap.ForMember(cm => cm.States, mc => mc.MapFrom(co => co.States));

Comment: I copied your code, and it works fine for me. The only difference is that I'm not inheriting from Entity and IValidatableObject so it might be something there.

Comment: Are you sure that you call Autmapper.CreateMap before you do the actual mapping?

Comment: @toree oh my god its my mistake, i was executed this code from Nunit test, and my automapper bootstrapping depends Dependency Injection,unfortunately the Setup attribute of nunit not worked well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have only defined a mapping from Country to CountryDto.
You might need an opposite too

Answer (score 0):

`Automapper` handles collections automatically, so your mapping definition is just fine.

You should, however, provide a public setter for `States` in `Country`.